# Distributed testing configuration

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Got to perform some load testing but got stuck. I want to remotely run tests from our TeamCity server.

I setup the jmeter.properties on client and server machine the same way: 
Remote hosts and RMI configuration:

```
server_port=7000
client.rmi.localport=7000
server.rmi.port=7000
server.rmi.localport=7000
```

on client machine remote_host=10.XXX.X.X

jmeter-server file:

```
RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.XXX.X.X
```

I can telnet to the TC, but whenever i launch the jmeter-server plus scripts from the master computer i get suck on :

```
remote engines have been started
waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445
```

and the remote host shows only the following :

```
Starting the test on host X.XXX.X.X:7000
```

i cannot see any threads running or results from the listener being written. Any help?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

On the remote server you shouldn't have to change anything in the properties file. Just simply run the jmeter-server.bat file, a command prompt window will open and sit there. If you really need to use port 7000 then only put this in the jmeter.properties file of the remote load generator
`server.rmi.localport=7000`

On the machine where you are running the test, in the jmeter.properties file, all you need to change is the 'remote_hosts' value.

```
remote_hosts=10.XXX.X.X:7000
```

You should be able to see if the remote hosts work by opening the test in GUI mode. In the JMeter menus you should see a remote host listed which you can select and then run the test.

Otherwise on the command line you should be able to run in non-GUI mode:

```
jmeter -n -t script.jmx -l logfile.log -r
```

If logfile.log gets populated with data you know the test is running.